# .setDefaultMemberPermissions is not working in my discord.js bot

Tags: discord, permissions, discord.js, bots

I've been trying to make a bot and i discovered the setdefaultmemberpermission, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Could someone help out please? When i execute the command without the administrator  permission, it still allows me to do the command.

Here is my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('embed')
        .setDescription('Sends a embed!')
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ADMINISTRATOR),
```

Comment: It's just a typo, `PermissionFlagsBits.ADMINISTRATOR` should be `PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```js
PermissionFlagsBits.ADMINISTRATOR
```

To this:

```js
PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator
```

Reference: [PermissionsBitFeld#Flags](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/PermissionsBitField?scrollTo=s-Flags), [PermissionFlagBits](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-payloads/common#PermissionFlagsBits)